# A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting this error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations

when I run this code:

```
SELECT 
    @i = Users,
    (NAME + ' ' + Surname) AS names
FROM   
    dbo.HelpDeskUsers
WHERE  
    [names] LIKE @userid
```

I tried another way ...

```
SET 
  @i = (SELECT  
            [Users],
            ([Name] + ' ' + [Surname]) AS [names]
        FROM  
            dbo.HelpDeskUsers
        WHERE  
            Names LIKE @userid)
```

and I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 17
>   Invalid column name 'Names'
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 19
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery
>   is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: What's your goal here? Do you want to assign `Users` value to `@i` also you want to show result of `Select` query

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Yes i do,  I also need to concat 2 columns as names with a where clause SQL-Server

Comment: A `select` can either [assign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) values to variables or [return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) column values, but not both. In some cases, e.g. when using `select` to provide data to an `insert`, an [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause may be useful.  A tool well worth having in your pocket as it provides access to identity values from `insert` and both _before_ and _after_ values when used with `update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Alias` name in same `select` query `where` clause and you have so many other mistakes in your query

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
select @i=Users 
from dbo.HelpDeskUsers 
where Name + ' ' + Surname  = @userid
```

This is how query is logically processed

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

As you can see `SELECT` comes after `WHERE` clause you cannot use the *alias name* in `where` generated in `select`

Comment: Any reason for downvoting :/

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

```
SELECT @i = Users,
       ( NAME + ' ' + Surname ) AS names
FROM   dbo.HelpDeskUsers
WHERE  [names] LIKE @userid
```

What the above  statement says in general,you are trying to return data (name+surname) and also assign value to variable(users) which is not valid

Answer (score 0):

The following query would help you

```
;WITH [CTEUsers]
AS
(
SELECT  [Users]
        ,[NAME] + ' ' + [Surname] AS [names]
FROM    dbo.[HelpDeskUsers]
)

SELECT  @i = [Users] 
FROM    [CTEUsers] 
WHERE   [names] LIKE @userid
```